# How to resize Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to resize an Amazon EC2 instance, e.g. convert from a small instance to a large instance? If so, what is the easiest way to resize Amazon EC2 instance?

Like Rackspace Cloud Servers do with *Rebuild*, see screenprint:

[image]

- My instance uses EBS.

Answer (score 39):

1. In your AWS Management Console, go to the EC2 Tab.
2. Check the instance you want to change (from micro to large, for example)
3. Put the instance in a 'Stopped' state.
4. Click the 'Instance Actions' menu, and choose 'Change Instance Type'
5. Choose the level you want the instance to run at (small, medium, large)
6. Click 'Yes, Change'.
7. Restart the instance in question.

EASY AS PIE!

Comment: JUST MAKE SURE YOU HAVE YOUR ELASTIC IP SET UP AND ALLOCATED TO THE INSTANCE. INSTANCE'S IP WILL CHANGE RANDOMLY WHEN YOU RESTART YOUR INSTANCE. 

i used the default IP to set up my email images at 1st and i didn't know it is temporarily IP only. once i resized my instance and IP address and public DNS changed. and...

Comment: OMG finally question I was looking for. Elsewhere they say it's not possible, lol

Comment: Should one do a shutdown from within the instance (e.g. sudo shutdown -r now) before stopping or is stopping the instance just going to do the same thing?

Comment: @Kzqai - Sorry. I hadn't been paying attention to Stack. Generally speaking, when working with AWS, you should be stopping and starting the instances either via CLI or through their web portal, and not from within the OS of the instance itself.

Answer (score 3):

- [Shrinking Amazon EBS volume size](https://serverfault.com/questions/183552/shrinking-amazon-ebs-volume-size)
- http://alestic.com/2010/02/ec2-resize-running-ebs-root

Comment: And what if I want to go from micro to large instance? Creating AMI is the only way?

Comment: I assumed you were talking about resizing the image. You can stop a machine and start it on any size instance that has space. http://alestic.com/2010/05/ec2-move-ebs-boot-instance